# How to solve the error 'AttValue: " or expected?

Tags: r

The following code uses Google API to find the distance between two locations. On running the code, it gave the error as given below. Please suggest how to solve this error.

```
> gmapsdistance(origin = "PAWTUCKET+LOWELL+MA", destination =
"INDUSTRIAL WAY+SALEM+NH", combinations = "all", mode = "driving", key
= "My_key")
```

> Error:
>   1: AttValue: " or ' expected 
>   2: attributes construct error 
>   3: Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 2 
>   4: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: Please see my solution below and let me know if you have any trouble. If this fixes it for you please click the check mark to let future readers know there's a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are no issues with using spaces my `googleway` package

```
library(googleway)

apiKey <- 'your_api_key'

google_distance(origins = list("PAWTUCKET+LOWELL+MA"), 
                destinations = list("INDUSTRIAL WAY+SALEM+NH"),
                mode = "driving",
                key = apiKey)

# $destination_addresses
# [1] "Industrial Way, Salem, NH 03079, USA"
# 
# $origin_addresses
# [1] "Pawtucket Blvd, Lowell, MA 01854, USA"
# 
# $rows
# elements
# 1 23.2 km, 23150, 27 mins, 1648, 27 mins, 1605, OK
# 
# $status
# [1] "OK"
```

---

Having said that, and as Hack-R alluded to in their answer, your actual error occurs because you have a space in your `destination` ("INDUSTRIAL WAY+SALEM+NH"). Replace this with a `+` and it will work.

```
gmapsdistance(origin = "PAWTUCKET+LOWELL+MA", 
              destination = "INDUSTRIAL+WAY+SALEM+NH", 
              combinations = "all",
              mode = "driving", 
              key = 'api_key')

$Time
[1] 1591

$Distance
[1] 23150

$Status
[1] "OK"
```

From the documentation `?gmapsdistance`

> If more than one word for a same location is used, they should be separated by a plus sign e.g. "Bogota+Colombia"

The actual error comes from the `XML` package, which is used by `gmapsdistance` under the hood.

Comment: You don't need the API key. The rest of the solution was covered in my answer 8 hours earlier.

Comment: @Hack-R the purpose for my post was to highlight the specific error (which I believe your original answer before the edit was a bit misleading), AND to highlight an alternative method for getting the solution. I've edited and credited you in my post. And, it wasn't me who down-voted you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were missing a `+` in the destination. I verified that this works when the syntax and precision are corrected.

**Proof:**

```
gmapsdistance(origin = "100+PAWTUCKET+ST+LOWELL+MA", 
              destination = "INDUSTRIAL+WAY+SALEM+NH",
              mode = "driving")
```

> ```
> $Time
> [1] 1506
>
> $Distance
> [1] 19223
>
> $Status
> [1] "OK"
> ```

Incidentally, you don't need an API key for this.

Comment: The issue is with the missing `+` only; Google has no issue finding the addresses as specified

Comment: @SymbolixAU Well, it did in my experiment, but either way I think you'll agree that I found the solution